# User with execution grant of a procedure that connects to other databases?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a user that have grants to execute one procedure into one SQL Server 2008 R2 database.

This procedure connects to other databases but execution fails for this user, because it do not see this other databases.

How can I have a user with execution grants of some procedures in a single database where this procedures connects to other databases?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The login used for execution needs permission to do what your procedure does on the target database(s) the procedure is working on.

Comment: Then, I need to otorgate select grants to each table that the procedure use?

Comment: Yes, it needs at least SELECT grant on the other databases to work.

Comment: There is no other option to simulate this grants? Because in the procedure I process this data to show what I want of each table, and not the full data.

Comment: You could use EXECUTE AS statement
CREATE PROCEDURE Stored.Procedure   
@Value int  
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER

Comment: I am using execute as owner and execute as 'user1' both have acces to the other database, but it does not works. In first case the error is: "Ca not be executed as the security entity of database because the "dbo" entity does not exist. This type of security entity can not be suplented or the user does not have grants". In the second case it says that the user does not have grant when it has.

Comment: You need an user that exists in the database, I would suggest creating one with the permissions needed rather than use dbo or any other standard user.
GRANT IMPERSONATE ON USER:: user2 TO user1;  
GO

Comment: The code I entered is to give impersonate grant on the user (dbo, user2) to your user (user1), without the grant the EXECUTE AS will fail.